# How to parse XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've this code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19");
echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
```

If I visit http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19 directly on the browser, I can see the XML return but when I tried the above code, only `HostipLookupResultSet<br />` gets echoed.

How do I retrieve the data from this xml? I'm interested in getting coutry and country abbreviation.

I was trying something like `echo $xml->HostipLookupResultSet->gml:featureMember->Hostip->countryName` but it seems it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work if you [query using xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) :-

```
// optional for register namespace into xpath
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gml', 'http://www.opengis.net/gml');

$result = $xml->xpath('//*[self::countryName or self::countryAbbrev]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the namespace. 
See the code bellow

```
/* @var $xml SimpleXMLElement */
echo $xml->getName() . "\n";
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();

foreach($xml->children($namespaces['gml']) as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try the following code for getting Country and Country Abbrevation:


$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19");
$cntry= $xml->xpath('//gml:featureMember');

foreach($cntry as $child) {
    echo $child->Hostip->countryName;
echo "<br />";
echo $child->Hostip->countryAbbrev;
}
```